# How to get values of Inputs through class name in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have group of input elements:

```
    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="mandate" />
    <input type="text" name="MiddleName" class="mandate" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" class="mandate" />
    <input type="text" name="Address" class="mandate" />'
```

In Jquery, it is very easy to get values through Class or we can easily perform some common event on the basis of class that all input elements have like

```
$('.mandate').each(function(){
console.log("Some....")
});
```

But I am wandering How it will be done in Angular 2.I am a completely newbie in Angular 2.

Comment: Read up https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: is it in test or in actual code

Comment: Right Now I am working on POC on Angular 2 and I want to apply error Count in form, So I need to get values and perform some actions/events on class basis like we do in the jquery.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you can use the [view children](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) in your component. This will let you select all elements in the template similarly to how jquery does.

```
@ViewChildren('.mandate') mandates;

mandates.forEach((mandate) =>{
     //do something here
});
```

This will retrieve all elements with class mandate as an array and will update with angular change detection.

Comment: @oreofeolurin I think you have misread what he is asking. He says nothing about forms but rather asks how to select all elements based on a class name.

Comment: Look at the tags he provided, Besides Angular form is a better, easier way to go

Comment: @oreofeolurin Regardless, his question is about looping over elements. Angular forms will not give him this ability.

Comment: @oreofeolurin Easier for what? You have no idea what he wants to do with these elements outside of loop over them.

Comment: Well lets say he didn't explain enough.......... don't worry I have removed the down-vote,

Comment: @oreofeolurin Agreed, if we knew more we could probably narrow it down to a better choice of resources

Comment: @Ankit If this works for you please accept the answer to help others looking for the same answer.

Comment: @Ankit can you give errors you are seeing? ViewChildren must be imported from angular core i believe

Comment: @rustin, There is no an error but when I am going to iterate that, there is nothing printing on the console. Might be the way I am using viewChildren is wrong.

Comment: @Ankit if you post your updated code I can help you debug

Comment: @rustin, Thanks a lot for your time. I have achieved what I want to implement. Onve again thank you

Answer (score 2):

you can use element reference (`ElementRef`) in angular and querySelector the way you used in jQuery.

```
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  // this is inside any of the method
  // this is to select multiple 
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.mandate');

  // this is to select single
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.mandate')
```

Comment: this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.mandate'); this is not returning anything

Comment: it should give a list of items and you should do a .map to loop over all of them

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake, actually I was using some different class name in my componnet thats why it was not returning anything, but now it is working fine. Thanks.