# Perform Events on Class/Ids in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am totally a newbie in Angular2. My Question is how I can perform common event on same classes, In Jquery it is very easy to do so, but I am not able to find the way to implement it in Angular2. Example is:

```
<input class="perform" value="Hello Angular" />
<input class="perform" value="Hello World" />
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
$('document.body').on('click','.perform', function(){
console.log("Value-->"+$this.value);
});
```

But how can we achieve the same thing in Angular2. Please Help.

Comment: heres a post trying to do the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370628/how-to-get-values-of-inputs-through-class-name-in-angular-2/46370694?noredirect=1#comment79703036_46370694

Answer (score 0):

You can use element reference to grab the element like in jQuery and then add event listener the way you have been doing in jquery.

#### example

```
<input class="perform" value="Hello Angular" (click)="makeClick($event)" />
<input class="perform" value="Hello World"  (click)="makeClick($event)"/>
```

in your component you can have a method to handle that event

```
makeClick(event: any) {
  //this is where you handle the event
}
```

If you need to do some style related things you can also do this way but not sure click will work on query selector.

```
   this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.perform').style.display = cancelEdit ? 'flex' : 'none';
```

Comment: but for this I have to bind (click) event for all inputs element, and I dont want to do so. Is there any other way.

Comment: Try to see if there is any event binding on query selector. see all the mothods availabele. `this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.perform')`

Comment: I dont remember anything else is there in angular

Answer (score 0):

Create directive (note that `selector` could be any valid css selector statement, not necessarily simple attribute)

```
@Directive({
    selector: [myKoolClickHandler]
})
export class MyKoolClickHandlerDirective{
    constructor(){}

    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
        console.log("clicked");
    }
}

//in template
<div my-kool-click-handler>Hi!</div>
<div my-kool-click-handler>Hi again!</div>
```